# How to remove dir background in `ls -color` output

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, ls

I use default Linux Mint .bashrc, here is [full bashrc](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a5fa37b387d76de7c94c28afcfbab3ad), the output is like:

[image]

some dir has green background, How to remove it?

Comment: Try to remove the alias: `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Comment: @MarounMaroun I hope keep color but change "green background", for ex, change it to "red background"

Comment: The simplest and cleanest is `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'tw=00;33:ow=01;33:'; export LS_COLORS`, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574819/how-to-remove-dir-background-in-ls-color-output#64590378).

Answer (score 28):

#### Quick solution:

Enter these two commands in the Bash command line:

```
dircolors -p | sed 's/;42/;01/' > ~/.dircolors
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

#### Explanation:

There is a program `dircolors` intended to set up the config for `ls`.
The default `~/.bashrc` script loads the config with these lines:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
```

Because by default the file `~/.dircolors` does not actually exist the script uses the built-in Bash config (`eval "$(dircolors -b)"`).

To remove green background for `o+w` ('writable by others' permission marked by last '`w`' in `drwxrwxrwx` notation in `ls`) directories you need to create this file basing on the current (built-in) config. In the command line type the following:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

`dircolor -p` prints the current config and `>` redirects the output to the given file.

Now open the file in an editor and find the following line:

```
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

change the number `42` (denoting green background) to `01` (no background) and save changes. Alternatively you can do it with `sed` program and its substitution feature (`'s/PATTERN/NEW_STRING/'` syntax) from the command line directly:

```
sed -i 's/;42/;01/' ~/.dircolors
```

Above 2 things can be achieved by a single command using a pipe '`|`':

```
dircolors -p | sed 's/;42/;01/' > ~/.dircolors
```

To get the change to take the effect (without restarting the shell), type:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: For this method to work, I'd to put `eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)"` in my `.bashrc` as Bash 5.0.18 doesn't automatically pick up `~/.dircolors` or `~/.dir_colors` [as the man page says](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors) on macOS 10.15.7.

Answer (score 22):

To remove all background colors, stick the following into your ~/.bashrc :

```
eval "$(dircolors -p | \
    sed 's/ 4[0-9];/ 01;/; s/;4[0-9];/;01;/g; s/;4[0-9] /;01 /' | \
    dircolors /dev/stdin)"
```

Comment: They are removed for the output of `ls`, but they still show when using autocomplete in zsh. Any workaround for this?

Comment: The colors for ls are set in the LS_COLORS environment variable, if the zsh code uses these colors it should work correctly, if it uses something else it will not work.

Comment: I found the issue. For some weird reason, the `eval` needs to be defined after the `plugins`, but before `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` (I use Oh My Zsh), otherwise it's not fully loaded.

Answer (score 14):

`LS_COLORS` is the variable that's referred by `ls` for colouring its output.  If `LS_COLORS` isn't set, it's generated using `dircolors` behind the scenes.  This can be set manually too with/out using `dircolors` (see *Vivid* below).

If most defaults work and you want only a few to be fixed, the easiest is to just set them in your `.bashrc`.

```sh
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'tw=00;33:ow=01;33:'; export LS_COLORS
```

This replaces the background colour (`42`) with normal(`00`) and bold (`01`) for

1. Others-writable directories with sticky bit set (`tw`)
2. Others-writable directories without sticky bit (`ow`)

This is the simplest solution since we keep the defaults for the rest.

The other answer's technique

```sh
# -b: make dircolors generate for bash
# sed replaces offending background colors
# sed's output is fed as input for another instance of dircolors
# the entire subshell returns LS_COLORS that's `eval`uated
eval $(dircolors -b | sed 's/ 4[0-9];/ 01;/; s/;4[0-9];/;01;/g; s/;4[0-9] /;01 /' | dircolors /dev/stdin)
```

simply does this on the fly by getting all the colour values and replacing anything with a background (`4[0-9]`) with bold (`01`).

---

There're better alternatives avoiding all manual fiddling:

1. [LS_COLORS](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS) (the project; not to be confused with `$LS_COLORS`, the variable)

   - Curated set of colours for different file formats/extensions
   - Download latest version, evaluate and append to `.bashrc`

```sh
wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O $HOME/.config/LS_COLORS
echo 'eval $(dircolors -b "$HOME/.config/dircolors")' >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

2. [Vivid](https://github.com/sharkdp/vivid)

   - Multiple themes
   - Generates `LS_COLORS` on-the-fly
   - Set `$LS_COLORS` in `.bashrc` using `vivid` command that generates necessary colour codes based on theme

```sh
export LS_COLORS="$(vivid generate molokai)"
```

Both these tool colour schemes don't have background colour for directories of any kind.

Answer (score 5):

The explanation is given in the output of `dircolors -p`, e.g.,

[image: screenshot with dircolors -p]

Of course `dircolors` doesn't color *its* output.  I used this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

our $comment = "\e[31m";
our $reset   = "\e[K\e[m";

our @data;

open my $fh, "dircolors -p|" or die "cannot read from dircolors";
@data = <$fh>;
close $fh;

printf "\e[H\e[2J";

for my $n ( 0 .. $#data ) {
    chomp $data[$n];
    if ( $data[$n] =~ /^\s*#/ ) {
        printf "%s%s%s\n", $comment, $data[$n], $reset;
    }
    elsif ( $data[$n] =~ /^\s*TERM\s/ ) {
        printf "%s\n", $data[$n];
    }
    elsif ( $data[$n] =~ /^\s*[^\s]+\s+\d+(;\d+)?\s*(#.*)?$/ ) {
        my $code = $data[$n];
        $code =~ s/^\s*[^\s]+\s+//;
        $code =~ s/\s.*//;
        my $data = $data[$n];
        $data =~ s/(#.*)$/$comment$1$reset/;
        $data =~ s/^(\s*)([^\s]+)(\s+)/$1\e[${code}m$2\e[m$3/;
        printf "%s\n", $data;
    }
    else {
        printf "%s\n", $data[$n];
    }
}

1;
```

To get rid of the background, you can either change the directory permissions, or use a different database to set your `LS_COLORS` environment variable.   The [`dircolors` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors) is the place to go.