# What are the color codes of ls function?

Tags: unix, colors, ls

For an exercise I'm trying to code the `ls` function.

I'm copying the `-G` option.
This option will color the name of the file depending of the type.

Until now, I understood that:

- Symbolic links are in magenta
- Directory is in cyan

Does any one know which are the other colors used and for what kind of file?
I'm also looking for the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I showed a script in *[How to remove dir background in `ls -color` output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574819/how-to-remove-dir-background-in-ls-color-output/40575734#40575734)* which colorizes the output of `dircolors -p` (and would be useful in this question, since it preserves the comments which explain what's being colored).

Answer (score 0):

The colors used by `ls` are determined by the `LS_COLORS` environment variable; or else by a builtin database. The environment variable `LS_COLORS` is normally set by evaluating the output of `dircolors`; see [`man dircolors`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dircolors.1.html) for details. Use `dircolors -p | less` to see the current values.